# alamofire-Pass json string as parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, afnetworking, alamofire

I want to pass the json string as parameter, but it only allows dictionary:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST,"myURL", parameters: "HERE I WANT STRING", encoding: .JSON).responseJSON
 { response in
    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                }
            }
```

I think my server accepts parameters as a json format.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to remove the question body from the code sample, which is indented by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide any additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Dont worry about that .
Just make Json as this and use as parameter

```
let jsonObject: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "status": "0" , "secondparameter" : "something"]


Alamofire.request(.POST,"myURL", parameters : jsonObject , encoding: .JSON).responseJSON
 { response in
    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                }
            }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: it sends json object as --  ["warehouse_details": {
    city = Kraft;
    country = DZ;
    "postal_code" = 9756;
    session = "mkl";
    "warehouse_name" = lol;
}]

Comment: and what backend wants is : {"warehouse_details": { city = Kraft; country = DZ; "postal_code" = 9756; session = "mkl"; "warehouse_name" = lol; }}

Comment: Can you confirm from server side , exactly what you getting as input parameter . As in alamofire you are encoding it as Json .

Comment: when we convert json object to string it will be  {"":""} , so i want to send the request in this format i mean {"":""} not ["":""]. so alamofire sends ["":""] thats why it does not work , if i use native method of apple than it works fine var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()

Comment: hey I think your problem is not ["" : ""] as I am using it and its working just fine , also my backend is accepting {"":""}, same for both android and ios . I checked the log on backend and its showing as {"":""} while I am sending parameter as ["":""] . So my guess is  encoding: .JSON comes into the play before sending it to server . Please check and revert it back so we can clear our doubt .

Comment: i think i should make mutable request.

Comment: Welcome! and happy that its got sorted out :)